# Projectitem unavailable when trying to save a form that contains a StatusStrip

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, designer, statusstrip

I added an empty status strip in my empty form and when I try to save this error pops up one time:

[image: The thrown error]

On the next attempt I can save until I change the `StatusStrip`. When I start the application or re-open the designer it will show my `StatusStrip`, but none of my added buttons in the `StatusStrip`. However, the produced designer code still contains the code of the buttons.

Does anybody experienced this bug or is there any way to get further information to solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Restarting Visual Studio solved this temporary issue at me.